# refactor for more concise and performant code

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to create a multidimensional array in the form of a multiplication table. And the table length will be the only argument. So if argument n = 4 the expected output would be -

[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[3,6,9,12],[4,8,12,16]]

this is my solution but I feel like it could be more concise and performant...

```
  let array = [];
  let indexes = n;
  let groups = n;
  //---Loop for the groups
  for(let g = 0; g < groups; g++){
    //---Create multidimensional array
    array[g] = [];
    //---Loop for the indexes of the each group
    for(let i = 0; i < indexes; i++){
      array[g][i] = (g + 1) * (i + 1);
    }
  }
  return array;
};
```

Comment: Is the performances actually an issue? Is making it “more concise” really important enough to worry about?

Comment: not a huge deal... I just wanted to see if there was a better way besides nesting for loops

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with the built in mapper.

```js
const
    getTable = length => Array.from(
        { length },
        (_, i) => Array.from(
            { length },
            (__, j) => (i + 1) * (j + 1)
        )
    );


getTable(4).forEach(a => console.log(...a));

getTable(3).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: this is 66% slower than asker's solution when length=1000 though...

Comment: @deterjan how did you determine that this answer was 66% slower... just curious?

Comment: @deterjan thank you, and thanks for the answer Nina !